# build custom framework to run on device

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, frameworks

I have two custom frameworks that they will not build correctly on a device. This is their current Active Architecture settings. How can I adjust things so they run on a simulator and device?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I changed the framework build device to a device and then added to my project. it worked.